# how to get max value of column from joined tables?

Tags: postgresql, count, max

I have two tables - `event(name)` and `ticket(event_name)`

I'd like to get only event name with max event_count. When I try to use `MAX(COUNT(event_name))` instead of `0` I get an error. It should print only `Sun|2`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT event_name, COUNT(event_name) AS ticket_count
FROM event INNER JOIN ticket ON name=event_name
GROUP BY event_name
HAVING COUNT(event_name) > 0
ORDER BY ticket_count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Does this help you?